# What is the difference between statements inside onMount and ouside onMount lifecycle?

Tags: lifecycle, svelte

It seem to me (I know I'll be wrong) that things I do inside `onMount` lifecycle function in **svelte** can also be done outside it. Is there a difference? or.. I'm missing huge points.

```
<script>

  import {onMount} from 'svelte'

  function doSomething() {
    // ......
    // ..........
  }

  onMount(() => {
    function doSomething() {
      // ......
      // ..........
    }
  })

</script>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As stated in the [API documentation](https://svelte.dev/docs#onMount), `onMount` will run when the component is added to the DOM, and only then.

Statements ran outside the `onMount` callback will execute when the component is mounted, but also when the component is ran in SSR.

Usually you put things inside the `onMount` callback statement that will need the DOM to be available, or that can't be executed Server Side when using SSR for various reasons.